# postgresql unique non-sequential id for url

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I've looked a few methods of creating alphanumeric IDs on Stackoverflow, but they all had their weaknesses, some did not check for collision and others used sequences which are not a good option when using logical replication.

After some Googling I found [this](https://blog.andyet.com/2016/02/23/generating-shortids-in-postgres/) website that has the following script which checks for collisions and does not use sequences. However this is done as a trigger when a row is inserted into the table.

```
-- Create a trigger function that takes no arguments.
-- Trigger functions automatically have OLD, NEW records
-- and TG_TABLE_NAME as well as others.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unique_short_id()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

 -- Declare the variables we'll be using.
DECLARE
  key TEXT;
  qry TEXT;
  found TEXT;
BEGIN

  -- generate the first part of a query as a string with safely
  -- escaped table name, using || to concat the parts
  qry := 'SELECT id FROM ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ' WHERE id=';

  -- This loop will probably only run once per call until we've generated
  -- millions of ids.
  LOOP

    -- Generate our string bytes and re-encode as a base64 string.
    key := encode(gen_random_bytes(6), 'base64');

    -- Base64 encoding contains 2 URL unsafe characters by default.
    -- The URL-safe version has these replacements.
    key := replace(key, '/', '_'); -- url safe replacement
    key := replace(key, '+', '-'); -- url safe replacement

    -- Concat the generated key (safely quoted) with the generated query
    -- and run it.
    -- SELECT id FROM "test" WHERE id='blahblah' INTO found
    -- Now "found" will be the duplicated id or NULL.
    EXECUTE qry || quote_literal(key) INTO found;

    -- Check to see if found is NULL.
    -- If we checked to see if found = NULL it would always be FALSE
    -- because (NULL = NULL) is always FALSE.
    IF found IS NULL THEN

      -- If we didn't find a collision then leave the LOOP.
      EXIT;
    END IF;

    -- We haven't EXITed yet, so return to the top of the LOOP
    -- and try again.
  END LOOP;

  -- NEW and OLD are available in TRIGGER PROCEDURES.
  -- NEW is the mutated row that will actually be INSERTed.
  -- We're replacing id, regardless of what it was before
  -- with our key variable.
  NEW.id = key;

  -- The RECORD returned here is what will actually be INSERTed,
  -- or what the next trigger will get if there is one.
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I have have a table which already contains data, I have added a new column called `pid` would it be possible to modify this and use the function call as default so all my prior data gets a short id?

Comment: You can just update the existing rows with the same key generation. The sum total is `replace(replace(encode(gen_random_bytes(6), 'base64'), '/', '_'), '+', '-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a table `test`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (foo text, bar int);
INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2);
```

You could add an `id` column to it:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN id text;
```

and attach the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS unique_short_id_on_test ON test;
CREATE TRIGGER unique_short_id_on_test
    BEFORE INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unique_short_id();
```

Now make a temporary table, `temp`, with the same structure as test (but with no data):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TABLE temp (LIKE test INCLUDING ALL);
CREATE TRIGGER unique_short_id_on_temp
    BEFORE INSERT ON temp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unique_short_id();
```

Pouring `test` into `temp`:

```
INSERT INTO temp (foo, bar)
SELECT foo, bar
FROM test
RETURNING *
```

yields something like:

```
| foo        | bar | id       |
|------------+-----+----------|
| A          |   1 | 9yt9XQwm |
| B          |   2 | LCeiA-P8 |
```

If other tables have foreign key references on the `test` table or if `test` must remain online,
it may not be possible to drop `test` and rename `temp` to `test`.
Instead, it is safer to update `test` with the `id`s from `temp`.

Assuming `test` has a primary key (for concreteness,  let's call it, `testid`), then
you could update `test` with the `id`s from `temp` using:

```
UPDATE test
SET id = temp.id
FROM temp
WHERE test.testid = temp.testid;
```

Then you could drop the `temp` table:

```
DROP TABLE temp;
```